# how to NOT apply border-right to the last child of a div- CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is my html:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span></span>
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
   // some html content
 </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span></span>
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
   // some html content
 </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span></span>
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
   // some html content
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

now i want to apply `border-right` property to the `child` class.
I did:

```
.parent.child:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid tpBorderColor;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

I also tried:

```
.parent.child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
.parent.child-child {
  border:none;
}
```

Both of them results in not showing the border to any of the divs.
any idea how to work this?

Comment: i thought you wanted to NOT apply border-right. ur title is really confusing

Comment: sorry, my bad, i meant the last child of the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it was you are looking for but, since your `.child` element is next to a `.child` element in the dom you can simply use something like this:

```
.child + .child {
  border-left: 1px solid currentColor;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

This affects the `.child` that is next to a `.child`

```css
.child + .child {
  border-left: 1px solid currentColor;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span>343</span>
            <label>sfs</label>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span>sfa</span>
            <label>afa</label>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span>343</span>
            <label>asfdfaf</label>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there. Just made some minor changes.

Try this.

```css
.parent .child:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.child {
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span>343</span>
            <label>sfs</label>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span>sfa</span>
            <label>afa</label>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span>343</span>
            <label>asfdfaf</label>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you supplied, any borders applied to `<div class="child">` would not be visible because there is no content within the HTML elements.

With that being said, you also would need to update your CSS.

This is because currently, you are styling all elements with `class="parent child"` but none of your elements have both selectors in a single class. Because the classes (parent > child) are nested you will need a space between them in your CSS file (see below).

```css
.parent .child:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid tpBorderColor;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

For example,

```html
<style>
    .parent .child:not(:last-child) {
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
</style>

<div class="main">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span></span>
            <label></label>
        </div>
        <div class="child2">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span>// some html content</span>
            <label></label>
        </div>
        <div class="child2">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span>// some html content</span>
            <label></label>
        </div>
        <div class="child2">
            // some html content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the first instance of the styled element is not rendered in the above example because there is no content.

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <span></span>
        <label></label>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        // some html content
    </div>
</div>
```